# Who created the Oracle and the Architect?

Tags: the-matrix

If Architect and Oracle are old programs which created the matrix. Does it say anywhere who built them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The Architect

The Matrix Wiki explains that:

> The Architect **was constructed by other machines** in a human image to
>   understand the nature of humans

who in turn created The Matrix.

## The Oracle

Following the failure of the first Matrix, to understand humans, The Architect:

> turned to a more human intuitive program designed to understand human
>   nature and psychology to augment the framework of the next Matrix.

This program was The Oracle

([Source](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Architect))

It is not made clear whether The Architect created [The Oracle](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Oracle) or not.  On the one hand, it is possible that The Architect did create The Oracle to further his understanding of human nature and psychology.  On the other hand, **like The Architect, other machines may have created The Oracle**, as the Architect lacked sufficient understanding of human nature to imbue The Oracle with her intricate knowledge of humankind.  This second view is supported by the fact that The Oracle is considered 'the mother' (note, not the 'daughter') of the Matrix, whilst The Architect is considered to be 'the father'.

Comment: Does Wikia source this? Wikia isn't in and out of itself canon

Comment: @DVK unfortunately no, there is no reference provided.  I am assuming though that this is explained in some source but the author has neglected to reference it.